# Проблемы при установке последней версии Python в Debian 7

Tags: debian, юнит-тесты, makefile, python-3.6

Cтолкнулся с проблемой при установке последней версии Python (3.6.1, а затем и 3.6.2) из исходников.

```
./configure --enable-optimizations
make -j4
make test

    0:25:09 load avg: 0.00 [405/405/1] test_urllib2net failed
Resource 'ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/' is not available
Resource 'ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/' is not available
test test_urllib2net failed -- multiple errors occurred; run in verbose mode for details
380 tests OK.

1 test failed:
    test_urllib2net

24 tests skipped:
    test_bz2 test_curses test_dbm_gnu test_dbm_ndbm test_devpoll
    test_gdb test_idle test_kqueue test_lzma test_msilib
    test_ossaudiodev test_readline test_sqlite test_startfile test_tcl
    test_tix test_tk test_ttk_guionly test_ttk_textonly test_turtle
    test_winconsoleio test_winreg test_winsound test_zipfile64
Re-running failed tests in verbose mode
Re-running test 'test_urllib2net' in verbose mode
test_close (test.test_urllib2net.CloseSocketTest) ... ok
test_custom_headers (test.test_urllib2net.OtherNetworkTests) ... ok
test_file (test.test_urllib2net.OtherNetworkTests) ... ok
test_ftp (test.test_urllib2net.OtherNetworkTests) ... test_redirect_url_withfrag (test.test_urllib2net.OtherNetworkTests) ... ok
test_sites_no_connection_close (test.test_urllib2net.OtherNetworkTests) ... ok
test_urlwithfrag (test.test_urllib2net.OtherNetworkTests) ... ok
test_ftp_basic (test.test_urllib2net.TimeoutTest) ... skipped "Resource 'ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/' is not available"
test_ftp_default_timeout (test.test_urllib2net.TimeoutTest) ... ERROR
test_ftp_no_timeout (test.test_urllib2net.TimeoutTest) ... skipped "Resource 'ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/' is not available"
test_ftp_timeout (test.test_urllib2net.TimeoutTest) ... ERROR
test_http_basic (test.test_urllib2net.TimeoutTest) ... ok
test_http_default_timeout (test.test_urllib2net.TimeoutTest) ... ok
test_http_no_timeout (test.test_urllib2net.TimeoutTest) ... ok
test_http_timeout (test.test_urllib2net.TimeoutTest) ... ok

======================================================================
ERROR: test_ftp (test.test_urllib2net.OtherNetworkTests) (url='ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/README')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 1534, in ftp_open
    fw = self.connect_ftp(user, passwd, host, port, dirs, req.timeout)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 1580, in connect_ftp
    dirs, timeout)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 2377, in __init__
    self.init()
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 2386, in init
    self.ftp.connect(self.host, self.port, self.timeout)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/ftplib.py", line 152, in connect
    source_address=self.source_address)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/socket.py", line 722, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/test/test_urllib2net.py", line 218, in _test_urls
    f = urlopen(url, req, TIMEOUT)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/test/test_urllib2net.py", line 27, in wrapped
    return _retry_thrice(func, exc, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/test/test_urllib2net.py", line 23, in _retry_thrice
    raise last_exc
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/test/test_urllib2net.py", line 19, in _retry_thrice
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 1552, in ftp_open
    raise exc.with_traceback(sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 1534, in ftp_open
    fw = self.connect_ftp(user, passwd, host, port, dirs, req.timeout)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 1580, in connect_ftp
    dirs, timeout)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 2377, in __init__
    self.init()
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 2386, in init
    self.ftp.connect(self.host, self.port, self.timeout)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/ftplib.py", line 152, in connect
    source_address=self.source_address)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/socket.py", line 722, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error ftp error: timeout('timed out',)>

======================================================================
ERROR: test_ftp_default_timeout (test.test_urllib2net.TimeoutTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 1534, in ftp_open
    fw = self.connect_ftp(user, passwd, host, port, dirs, req.timeout)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 1556, in connect_ftp
    persistent=False)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 2377, in __init__
    self.init()
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 2386, in init
    self.ftp.connect(self.host, self.port, self.timeout)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/ftplib.py", line 152, in connect
    source_address=self.source_address)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/socket.py", line 722, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/test/test_urllib2net.py", line 304, in test_ftp_default_timeout
    u = _urlopen_with_retry(self.FTP_HOST)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/test/test_urllib2net.py", line 27, in wrapped
    return _retry_thrice(func, exc, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/test/test_urllib2net.py", line 23, in _retry_thrice
    raise last_exc
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/test/test_urllib2net.py", line 19, in _retry_thrice
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 1552, in ftp_open
    raise exc.with_traceback(sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 1534, in ftp_open
    fw = self.connect_ftp(user, passwd, host, port, dirs, req.timeout)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 1556, in connect_ftp
    persistent=False)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 2377, in __init__
    self.init()
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 2386, in init
    self.ftp.connect(self.host, self.port, self.timeout)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/ftplib.py", line 152, in connect
    source_address=self.source_address)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/socket.py", line 722, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error ftp error: timeout('timed out',)>

======================================================================
ERROR: test_ftp_timeout (test.test_urllib2net.TimeoutTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 1534, in ftp_open
    fw = self.connect_ftp(user, passwd, host, port, dirs, req.timeout)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 1556, in connect_ftp
    persistent=False)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 2377, in __init__
    self.init()
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 2386, in init
    self.ftp.connect(self.host, self.port, self.timeout)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/ftplib.py", line 152, in connect
    source_address=self.source_address)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/socket.py", line 722, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/test/test_urllib2net.py", line 323, in test_ftp_timeout
    u = _urlopen_with_retry(self.FTP_HOST, timeout=60)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/test/test_urllib2net.py", line 27, in wrapped
    return _retry_thrice(func, exc, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/test/test_urllib2net.py", line 23, in _retry_thrice
    raise last_exc
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/test/test_urllib2net.py", line 19, in _retry_thrice
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 1552, in ftp_open
    raise exc.with_traceback(sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 1534, in ftp_open
    fw = self.connect_ftp(user, passwd, host, port, dirs, req.timeout)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 1556, in connect_ftp
    persistent=False)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 2377, in __init__
    self.init()
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/urllib/request.py", line 2386, in init
    self.ftp.connect(self.host, self.port, self.timeout)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/ftplib.py", line 152, in connect
    source_address=self.source_address)
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/socket.py", line 722, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/user/distrib/Python-3.6.2/Lib/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error ftp error: timeout('timed out',)>

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 15 tests in 1107.933s

FAILED (errors=3, skipped=2)
test test_urllib2net failed
1 test failed again:
    test_urllib2net

Total duration: 43 min 38 sec
Tests result: FAILURE
make: *** [test] Ошибка 1
```

Comment: Уточнение: неделю назад всё ставилось на Debian 8. Сейчас на виртуальной машине с Debian 8 тест прошел успешно.

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, зачем вам аж Debian 7, если уже есть даже Debian 9?

Comment: Сервер поднят на Xen'е с поддержкой Debian 7. Debian 9 на нем не запустился. Причин, почему не обновлён Xen не знаю. Системным администратором не являюсь.

Comment: В сухом остатке: На Debian 8 тест проходит хорошо. На Debian 7: FAILED (errors=3, skipped=2)
test test_urllib2net failed
1 test failed again:
    test_urllib2net

Total duration: 43 min 38 sec
Tests result: FAILURE
make: *** [test] Ошибка 1

Comment: А там интернет-то есть? Судя по логу он просто не может достучаться до `ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/README`

Comment: @nobody Интернет есть. Я сначала грешил на недоступность ФТПшника в момент теста (в первый раз он действительно был недоступен). Во второй раз ФТПшник был доступен, но ошибка повторилась.

Comment: @Михаил а вы как проверяли доступность? Так же, как это делает test? Просто получается если это так, то скрипт сборки врёт... мне кажется на виртуалке либо проблема с conntrack , либо с NAT из-за чего может не работать ftp в активном режиме.

Comment: @nobody Я не знаю как это делает Тест. Я ещё только учусь. Во как... а инет есть. wget ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/README
--2017-07-19 16:39:42--  ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/README
           => «README»
Распознаётся ftp.debian.org (ftp.debian.org)... 130.89.148.12, 2001:610:1908:b000::148:12
Подключение к ftp.debian.org (ftp.debian.org)|130.89.148.12|:21... ошибка: Время ожидания соединения истекло.
Подключение к ftp.debian.org (ftp.debian.org)|2001:610:1908:b000::148:12|:21... ошибка: Сеть недоступна.

Comment: Из Debian 8 тоже доступа нет, однако тест проходит.